# Orchard is not displaying default page

Tags: orchardcms

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction.  Orchard will open any page my the home page.  For instance if I try to go to www.xxx.com I get the message "Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /"

I can get to other pages though if I type in the full url.

Anyone have any insight on what might be causing this.  I'm wondering if its a routing problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First place to check is the logs directory in the `\App_Data\` folder. It will have more detailed errors.

Try accessing `/admin/` to get into the admin panel. If you can then set the homepage to something. Some times you can end up without a homepage which causes problems.

Comment: Thanks.  It was the setting of the home page again that helped me clear this problem up.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: I was setting blank CMS site that is why it kept showing 404. Thanks heaps @rtpHarry you saved me.